# Dataframe: Clean cells containing specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| Name | Phone / Mail |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 0176348334 |
| Celine | celine@mail.com |
| ... | ... |

How do I edit all the cells containin "@"?

So the result should be like this:

| Name | Phone / Mail |
| --- | --- |
| Max | 0176348334 |
| Celine | Please fill in Phone Number |
| ... | ... |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Phone / Mail'].str.contains('@'), 'Phone / Mail'] = 'Please fill in Phone Number'
```

Or `np.where`:

```
df['Phone / Mail'] = np.where(df['Phone / Mail'].str.contains('@'), df['Phone / Mail'], 'Please fill in Phone Number')
```

Just filter the occurrences of the `@` sign.